# express server won't connect to port

Tags: node.js, express

its was work normally till i made some change then its won't connect to server
i make a new simple server but the same problem  =>
it hang in this line :

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
```

and not showing `server Running on port 5000`

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const CONNECTION_URL =
  'mongodb+srv://ripxxxx:ripxxxx@todo.moov4.mongodb.net/todxxxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(
    () => app.listen(PORT),
    () => console.log('server Running on port ' + PORT)
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second function that does the `console.log` and use it inside `app.listen` like below

```
mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(
    () => app.listen(PORT, console.log('server Running on port ' + PORT))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

or below also should work but don't do so

```
.then(() => app.listen(PORT))
.then(() => console.log("Meaningless to do like this" + PORT)
.catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```